# Проверить паспортные данные без ввода картинки

Tags: поиск

Добрый день!

По работе приходится часто проверять корректность паспортных данных на сайте http://services.fms.gov.ru/info-service.htm?sid=2000

Каждый раз вводить картинку очень неудобно, иногда приходится делать это несколько десятков раз в день. Может быть есть варианты проверять паспортные данные без этой картинки (возможно, даже, на платном сервисе, если такой есть)

Там есть ссылка на файл с недействительными паспортами, но он очень большой и работать с ним неудобно. Можно, конечно, автоматизировать его скачивание, импорт в базу и написание своего сервиса, но это слишком трудоемко и не покроет трудозатрат на ввод картинки руками.

Может быть есть способ проще?

Спасибо.

Comment: обратитесь в соответствующую службу - возможно Вам предоставят "эксклюзивный доступ". Или он больше не понадобится.

Comment: Есть сервисы по разгадыванию капч, стоят копейки.